# Getting a Smart Tag into a DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

You know in Visual Studio and other Microsoft products such as Word and Excel, there is that little question/exclamation mark symbol that appears, and if you click on it something drops down to tell you something about what's been entered at that point.

What is that, and could I put it in a cell in a DataGrid?

Comment: It's called a smart tag.

Comment: Thanks, can it be put into a DataGrid cell?

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature in the DataGrid that provides this. You can mark a cell or entire row as having an error and in that case the red circle with exclamation mark inside acts as the error indicator. Putting the mouse over that mark shows a tool tip with details about the error. But apart from that there is no option to go as you need.